# Debug mvn test in eclipse doesn't end

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, unit-testing, junit4

I cannot debug the tests in my spring boot application. I can debug the application but not the test, I am using eclipse 2021, spring boot 3.0.4, hibernate and junit 4.13.2 for the test.

If I do mvn test without debugging it works properly, but I want to debug to know the values of the variables, because I am getting an error only during the test phase.

**What I have tried**

- Restart project, mvn clean and then build the project again.
- Debug as junit test instead of mvn test.
- Debug test class individually, instead of debugging all the test in the project.
- Debug using mvn -DforkCount=0 test.
- Debug using mvn -Dtest=MySuperClassTest -Dmaven.surefire.debug test and then setting a remote configuration in eclipse.

None of them worked.

The debugger stop at this method in `Class.class`:

```
@CallerSensitive
public Field getDeclaredField(String name)
    throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(name);
    @SuppressWarnings("removal")
    SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (sm != null) {
        checkMemberAccess(sm, Member.DECLARED, Reflection.getCallerClass(), true);
    }
    Field field = searchFields(privateGetDeclaredFields(false), name);
    if (field == null) {
        throw new NoSuchFieldException(name); //stops here
    }
    return getReflectionFactory().copyField(field);
}
```

I can resume after this, but then the debugger doesn't stop at any breakpoint and doesn't end, I have to stop it manually or activate the skip all breakpoints option to end the execution.

After resuming the previous code this is what I see in the console:

```
2023-07-11T14:27:39.877+02:00  INFO 12956 --- [           main] com.task.checkTasks.TaskTest             : Starting TaskTest using Java 17.0.2 with PID 12956 (started by jorge in C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\Task_Management\checkTasks)
 2023-07-11T14:27:40.089+02:00  INFO 12956 --- [           main] com.task.checkTasks.TaskTest             : The following 1 profile is active: "test"
```

I cannot advance from this point.

If I run the mvn test without debugging those are the errors:

```
2023-07-11T14:30:43.311+02:00  WARN 19192 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2023-07-11T14:30:43.311+02:00 ERROR 19192 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
Hibernate: insert into user (email, password, username, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-07-11T14:30:43.370+02:00  WARN 19192 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2023-07-11T14:30:43.370+02:00 ERROR 19192 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
Hibernate: insert into user (email, password, username, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-07-11T14:30:43.445+02:00  WARN 19192 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2023-07-11T14:30:43.445+02:00 ERROR 19192 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
[ERROR] Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.885 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.task.checkTasks.TaskTest
[ERROR] findTasksByDescriptionTest  Time elapsed: 0.453 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]
        at com.task.checkTasks.TaskTest.findTasksByDescriptionTest(TaskTest.java:108)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at com.task.checkTasks.TaskTest.findTasksByDescriptionTest(TaskTest.java:108)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
        at com.task.checkTasks.TaskTest.findTasksByDescriptionTest(TaskTest.java:108)

[ERROR] findAllTaskListByUserTest  Time elapsed: 0.021 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]
        at com.task.checkTasks.TaskTest.findAllTaskListByUserTest(TaskTest.java:83)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at com.task.checkTasks.TaskTest.findAllTaskListByUserTest(TaskTest.java:83)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
        at com.task.checkTasks.TaskTest.findAllTaskListByUserTest(TaskTest.java:83)

[ERROR] findAllTaskListByUser  Time elapsed: 0.031 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]
        at com.task.checkTasks.TaskTest.findAllTaskListByUser(TaskTest.java:200)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at com.task.checkTasks.TaskTest.findAllTaskListByUser(TaskTest.java:200)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
        at com.task.checkTasks.TaskTest.findAllTaskListByUser(TaskTest.java:200)
```

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like "mvn test without debugging" does not, in fact, work properly. Update your Eclipse version, fix your tests, and then see if you are able to debug them properly.

Comment: Why not running you test from your IDE or using debugging your test from your IDE... apart from that why do you use an old version of Eclipse 2021??? And a strange thing is why do you use JUnit 4 ... why not using JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5)... for testing?

Comment: I am running my test in my IDE, but in the IDE you have to set goals, when I do debug as maven test in the IDE it does mvn test, I think that is how the IDE works